# XML Parsing in java

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best method to parse various custom XML documents in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106/best-method-to-parse-various-custom-xml-documents-in-java)

HI all,

I am beginner to java. I hope the question I am asking may be easy one. My question is if I had an XML file and i want to parse it get the elements only with in specific tag.
for example if XML file looks like..

```
<date>2005-10-31</date>
<number>12345</number>

<purchased-by>
    <name>My name</name>
    <address>My address</address>
</purchased-by>

    <order-items>

    <item>
        <code>687</code>
        <type>CD</type>
        <label>Some music</label>
    </item>

    <item>
        <code>129851</code>
        <type>DVD</type>
        <label>Some video</label>
    </item>

</order-items>
```

And from this XML I want to parse only the elements with in the tag name order-items.

Is there any generic way to do this..?Please let me know..
Thanks

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you read up on how to parse XML in Java, try to figure it out yourself and post a question here — with a code sample — when you get stuck. A good place to start is a Google search for [java xml](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=java+xml).

Comment: Agree with @Marcelo Cantos this question has also been asked many times in SO, so you can do a search here.

Comment: Don't these people google? I've answered similar questions like these many times already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, a short Google Search should bring you to the [SUN examples on how to do this](http://java.sun.com/developer/codesamples/xml.html). Basically, you have two main XML parsing methods in Java :

- [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML), where you use an [handler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) to only grab what you want in your XML and ditch the rest
- [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), which parses your file all along, and allows you to grab all elements in a more tree-like fashion.

Another very useful XML parsing method, albeit a little more recent than these ones, and included in the JRE only since Java6, is [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX). StAX was conceived as a medial method between the tree-based of DOM and event-based approach of SAX. It is quite similar to SAX in the fact that parsing very large documents is easy, but in this case the application "pulls" info from the parser, instead of the parsing "pushing" events to the application. You can find more explanation on this subject [here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/09/17/stax.html).

So, depending on what you want to achieve, you can use one of these approaches.

Comment: StAX is another standard approach to XML parsing.  It is similar to SAX except you request (pull) the events.  A StAX parade is included in Java SE 6.

Comment: @Blaise : added a part about StAX

Comment: vtd-xml is the other one

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit the parsing operation itself to the `<order-items>` element, then you'll have to use SAX. A SAX parser visits all elements of the input "file" (or stream) and you can define, that the parser shall ignore anything that is *not* `<order-items>` or any of its children. The result will be a `Document` containing these elements only.

If the xml documents are rather small and performance is not a limiting factor, then simply parse the whole document (that's a 2-liner) and use XPath expressions to select the correct nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath. It lets you select nodes on their name and loads of other conditions. Very little code involved to setup.

[IBM Example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi.html)

Comment: `XPath` requires that you have already *parsed* (part of) the document. If the OP's wording is correct, he want's to limit the parsing operation to `<order-items>`. So in this case, xpath won't help.

Comment: @Andreas_D - I assume he meant that he does not care about the other elements and want the minimum fuss to reach the elements he is interested in. If this is a performance problem you are right though.

Comment: The javax.xml.xpath libraries do not require the input to be a DOM node.  Of course the document needs to be processed ( as with any approach), but an XPath implementation need not be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is a classic case for SAX. Register handler that receives tags and ignore all tags other than order-items.

Probably better way is to use Apache Digester but it is over-kill for your specific task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DOM Parser to build a [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) and then extract whatever elements you want using the `getElementsByTagName` method.

Here is some sample code to help you get started:

```
    //parse file and build Document
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("file.xml"));

    //get list of elements called order-items
    NodeList orderItemsNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("order-items");

    //iterate over the elements
    for(int i = 0 ; i <orderItemsNodes.getLength();i++ ){
        Node orderItemNode = orderItemsNodes.item(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It honestly depends on how you are planning to use the *item* data. If you want to parse it into object and then work with it, I would use jaxb marshalling, but if you just want to strip string values from *code*, *type*, and *label* attributes of each *item* element, you may just consider using simple regex matching on the xml string - match content for each *item* tag, then match each attribute and extract its value.