# how data can be parsing in xml parsing and data show in listview in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, listview

I have a doubt in xml parsing. How to do XML parsing in this type of example:

```
<companies>
  <company name="ramki" symbol="ram"/>
  <company name="addidas" symbol="ads"/>
  <company name="samsang" symbol="sam"/>
  .................
```

and also tell me how to show the in ListView (name and symbol also)

Comment: This question is right what i needed but i am unable to get the link to show parsed xml in listview.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an [excellent](http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html) tutorial on XML Parsing and for the second question [this](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/) should be helpful.

EDIT: After Posting your sample, i see that you'll needing the [Attributes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html) Field in the `startElement`

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                        String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException
```

use `atts.getValue("name")` to get the name...do the same for symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Two parts :

- for XML parsing, it's the same thing as in Java. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106/best-method-to-parse-various-custom-xml-documents-in-java) about XML parsing. As said in the [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) MGS provided, StaX is not implemented in Android, but can be easily replaced by the [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).
- As for displaying your data in a ListView, you'll juste have to use an [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). For more help about lists, see the [associated resource in Android Help](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

Answer (score 0):

go through this link and try the same by using Working with DOM parsing
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/,
to display parsed single content in Listview,simply use array adapter to set in Listview,if you want to show multiple items in list row go ahead for custom adapter.

I hope it may help you much....