# parsing XML in java

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best method to parse various custom XML documents in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106/best-method-to-parse-various-custom-xml-documents-in-java)

Hi, please tell me how to parse following xml file efficiently.

```
<payload xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/task">
<AppealRequestProcessRequest xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AppealRequest">
   <creator>abhsihek</creator>
   <fromDate>2011-03-14+08:00</fromDate>
   <toDate>2011-03-14+08:00</toDate>
   <reason>reason checking</reason>
</AppealRequestProcessRequest>
</payload>
```

want to get the values creator, fromDate, toDate and reason....

I have written the following code:

```
            Element partEl = (Element) ta.getPayloadAsElement();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            String xmldata=XMLHelper.toXML(partEl);
             log.info("xmldata --"+xmldata);   

             /*at following line I am getting exception                    */
                 Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmldata);
             doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();                  
      System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
                 NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
                 System.out.println("-----------------------");                  
                 for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
                 {                  
                    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);     
                    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                    {                  
                       Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                       System.out.println("creator : "  + getTagValue("creator",eElement));
                       System.out.println("fromDate : "  + getTagValue("fromDate",eElement));
                       System.out.println("toDate : "  + getTagValue("toDate",eElement));
                       System.out.println("reason : "  + getTagValue("reason",eElement));   
                       flag=true;
                                       }
                 }          

           }
```

I am getting exception:

> no protocol: 
>   abhsihek
>   2011-03-14+08:00 
>   2011-03-14+08:00
>   reason checking
>   
>   
>   thks