# What is the most memory efficient method to parse XML in java?

Tags: java, xml, memory

I have memory problems with the webapp responsible from parsing XML event and pushing them to our RabbitMQ bus. This webapp receives XML event in a servlet, we decode it and push it to our bus and then we acknowledge the sender. We are curently using `org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler` in java 5, but it seems that [Stax](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=173) (with XMLStreamReader) is much better and still easy to read, but we would need to migrate our code to java6 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106/best-method-to-parse-various-custom-xml-documents-in-java) on SO). Does it worth it ?

What is the most memory efficient method to parse XML in java ? We are looking for a **fast**, **memory efficient** and easy to write/read code. Does this exist ?

Comment: I can't believe a SAX parser is causing memory problems. By it's nature SAX is stream-based so the memory overhead is very low. Are you doing something like caching the whole doc in memory?

Comment: we're no caching the doc in memory, we are reading the stream. The code was fine, but now we receive more events et we crach...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event-driven parsers don't build up ASTs and are therefore fast and memory-efficient. The standard for XML would be defined by the [SAX standard](http://www.saxproject.org/).

[The Xerces implementation claims to be fast.](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/)

Comment: I have found a significant increase in performance when using the latest Xerces (2.11.0) versus standard JAXP parser included in Java 1.6. It took only half the time to parse a large XML-file.

Comment: I thought I'd comment in case anyone had the same question - I believe AST is Abstract Syntax Tree

Answer (score 1):

[NanoXML](http://devkix.com/nanoxml.php) is a very small and lightweight XML parser which supports SAX parsing.  It is a good alternative to Xerces.

Comment: On further investigation, no, NanoXML is not memory efficient.

Comment: ok thanks, it is always cool to discover new libs from time to time

Comment: No problem.  I have used NanoXML in the past primarily to avoid the whole JDOM stack, since it's a very small (in the order of 20k last time I looked) jar file and the class structure is very flat.  But yes, memory footprint wasn't a consideration! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the answers mentioning Sax, as it is at the expense of significantly less usefulness. The most memory efficient sax parsing w/o sacrificing usability is [vtd-xml](http://vtd-xml.sf.net). Here is the proof

Processing XML with Java – A Performance Benchmark http://sdiwc.us/digitlib/journal_paper.php?paper=00000582.pdf