# Parse XML files Java with DOM

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am currently developing a system that uses the following format of XML files to for configuration purposes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Branch>
    <Department>
        <Door id="1" enabled="true"/>
        <Door id="2" enabled="true"/>
    </Department>
    <Department>
        <Door id="3" enabled="true"/>
        <Door id="4" enabled="false"/>
    </Department>
    <Department>
        ....
</Branch>
```

Do you know how could I parse this XML file?

I have been looking for other answers but I could only get it to work till the Department node. It isn't interpreting the Door node level.

Comment: What are you using now? Why does it not "interpret the Door"?

Comment: Java's default for parsing XML is the [SAX parser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html). Just google for "Java XML parser" for more options.

Comment: I am using DOM as I read is better and uses less resources than SAX. The computer where the app will run is very limited. Do you know how could I read this file? Thanks for your comments!!

Comment: I'm not sure what metric you're using to conclude "uses less resources than SAX", but the Java DOM parser APIs are going to take more memory and time than the SAX parser APIs.

Comment: Your question is basically this - [What is the most memory efficient method to parse XML in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332163/what-is-the-most-memory-efficient-method-to-parse-xml-in-java), and I do believe you are mistaken about SAX vs DOM resources.