# Fasterxml Jackson - XML Parsing Error - XML Tags starting with 0

Tags: java, xml, spring, resttemplate

I am using the Spring Framework to make an http call to parse a *xml* file:

**HTTP response**:

```
<ReducedContext>
    <workflowId>580ce4fa-d4e9-427e</workflowId>
    <runId>52f1773c-cfe9-47da</runId>
    <status>WORKFLOW_EXECUTION_STATUS</status>
    <steps>
        <steps>
            <stepTechnicalName>step1</stepTechnicalName>
            <variableReads>
                <variableReads>HASH_ARTEFACT</variableReads>
                <variableReads>RUN_ID</variableReads>
            </variableReads>
        </steps>
        <steps>
            <stepTechnicalName>step2</stepTechnicalName>
            <variableReads>
                <variableReads>VEHICLE</variableReads>
                <variableReads>UPDATE_ORDER</variableReads>
            </variableReads>
        </steps>
    </steps>
    <variables>
        <TOPOLOGY>
            <064E>
                <diagnosisAddressMaster>00C5</diagnosisAddressMaster>
                <diagnosisClass>2</diagnosisClass>
                <nodeAddress>004E</nodeAddress>
                <diagnosisAddress>064E</diagnosisAddress>
            </064E>
            <00A5>
                <diagnosisAddressMaster>00A5</diagnosisAddressMaster>
                <diagnosisClass>3</diagnosisClass>
                <nodeAddress>004F</nodeAddress>
                <diagnosisAddress>00A5</diagnosisAddress>
            </00A5>
            <8132>
                <diagnosisAddressMaster>8132</diagnosisAddressMaster>
                <diagnosisClass>4</diagnosisClass>
                <nodeAddress>0114</nodeAddress>
                <diagnosisAddress>8132</diagnosisAddress>
            </8132>
        </TOPOLOGY>
        <PR_NUMBERS>023</PR_NUMBERS>
        <PR_NUMBERS>025</PR_NUMBERS>
        <PR_NUMBERS>081</PR_NUMBERS>
        <PR_NUMBERS>099</PR_NUMBERS>
        <PR_NUMBERS>0E1</PR_NUMBERS>
    </variables>
</ReducedContext>
```

I'm trying to get the response via `RestTemplate.getForEntity`

```
final ResponseEntity<ResponseDto> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, ResponseDto.class, urlParameter);
```

And `ResponseDto` looks like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(chain = true)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResponseDto {
    private String workflowId;
    private List<Step> steps;
    private Map<String, Object> variables;
}
```

When trying to map between response and `ResponseDto`, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unexpected character '0' (code 48) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,5487]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character '0' (code 48) in content after '<' (malformed start element?).
```

I tried to delete tags starting with `0` (for example `<064E>`).

If I delete them, it's working, but I don't want to delete them, I need them.

What do you think I could do?

Answer (score 1):

tag `<064E>` is illegal:
Read up on the rules for XML tag names :
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

As a workaround you could use an `_` before the number character or write your custom xml parser  :
[Best method to parse various custom XML documents in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106/best-method-to-parse-various-custom-xml-documents-in-java)

Comment: That's true, but I don't think he controls the answer that he receives...

Comment: Yes , in that case he could use a Dom parser , but the first of how and why  a malformed XML is created also should be checked.

Comment: Yes, indeed @Matteo NNZ, I can't control the answer